# Typescript literal type union issue when type become more specific in react children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm working on converting our React/redux project to TypeScript and I'm facing an issue with TypeScript literal type union type.

Here is the issue:

I instantiate a *Wrapper* component with a *type* props (a string):

```
//index.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

import Wrapper from "./wrapper";

function App() {
  return <Wrapper type="password" />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I define, in this *Wrapper* component a "list" of string *type* value should fit with. To do this, I use a TypeScript Union type: `type: "value1" | value2 | ...`

```
//Wrapper.tsx

import * as React from "react";
import Input from "./input";
import Select from "./select";

interface ILabeledInput {
  type: "textarea" | "password" | "select" | "search" | "email" | "text";
}

export default function Wrapper(props: ILabeledInput) {
  switch (props.type) {
    case "select":
      return <Select {...props} />;

    case "password":
      return <Input {...props} />;
  }
}
```

Here I use a switch to instantiate the appropriate sub-component regardless to the type I had defined in *index.tsx*

In sub-components, I also use a typescript interface to define *type* prop type.
With this switch:

-*type*'s type could be just a string (only one possibility):

```
// select.tsx
import * as React from "react";

interface ISelect {
  type: "select";
}

export default function Input(props: ISelect) {
  return <p>{props.type}</p>; // fake code, juste to display something
}
```

-or once again a TypeScript Union type of strings (but with less possibility than the original one):

```
// input.tsx
import * as React from "react";

interface IInput {
  type: "password" | "search" | "email" | "text";
}

export default function Input(props: IInput) {
  return <p>{props.type}</p>; // fake code, juste to display something
}
```

The fact *type*'s type change from wrapper to select/input components generate a TypeScript error :

```
Type '{ type: "textarea" | "password" | "select" | "search" | "email" | "text"; }' is not assignable to type 'ISelect'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type '"textarea" | "password" | "select" | "search" | "email" | "text"' is not assignable to type '"select"'.
      Type '"textarea"' is not assignable to type '"select"'.ts(2322)
```

and

```
Type '{ type: "textarea" | "password" | "select" | "search" | "email" | "text"; }' is not assignable to type 'IInput'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type '"textarea" | "password" | "select" | "search" | "email" | "text"' is not assignable to type '"password" | "search" | "email" | "text"'.
      Type '"textarea"' is not assignable to type '"password" | "search" | "email" | "text"'.ts(2322)
```

I understand that Typescript detects a change in prop type, but I can't find how to make it consider the Switch condition.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
export default function Wrapper(props: ILabeledInput) {
    const {type, ...restProps} = props;
  switch (type) {
    case "select":
      return <Select {type: 'select', ...restProps} />;

    case "password":
      return <Input {type: 'password', ...restProps} />;
  }
}
```

However, since you declare your `props` to be of type `ILabeledInput`, according to your type definition there cannot be any other properties than `type`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to make your example more concise, assuming I've understood it correctly, and it works correctly for me. Does this address your issue?

```
type a = 'a';
type b = 'b';
type input = 'a' | 'b';

function takeA(a: a) { }

function takeB(b: b) { }

function takeBoth(input: input) {
  switch (input) {
    case 'a':
      return takeA(input);
    case 'b':
      return takeB(input);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys!
I spent my afternoon on this and finally found how to fix this, and it correponds to your solution alex.

I've start destructuring props juste like you :

```
import Input from "./input";
import Select from "./select";
interface ILabeledInput {
  type: "textarea" | "password" | "select" | "search" | "email" | "text";
}

export default function Wrapper(props: ILabeledInput) {
  const { type, ...props } = props;
  switch (props.type) {
    case "select":
      return <Select {...props} type={type} />;

    case "password":
      return <Input {...props} type={type} />;
  }
}
```

But keeping props.type as argument of the switch still generate an issue. So I decided to post this topic.

I finally get it work with these solutions:

```
import * as React from "react";

import Input from "./input";
import Select from "./select";
interface ILabeledInput {
  type: "textarea" | "password" | "select" | "search" | "email" | "text";
}

export default function Wrapper(props: ILabeledInput) {
  switch (props.type) {
    case "select":
      return <Select {...props} type={props.type} />;

    case "password":
      return <Input {...props} type={props.type} />;
  }
}
```

or

```
import * as React from "react";

import Input from "./input";
import Select from "./select";
interface ILabeledInput {
  type: "textarea" | "password" | "select" | "search" | "email" | "text";
}

export default function Wrapper(props: ILabeledInput) {
  const { type, ...rprops } = props;
  switch (type) {
    case "select":
      return <Select {...rprops} type={type} />;

    case "password":
      return <Input {...rprops} type={type} />;
  }
}
```

It seems that switch argument should be the same as the one pass to sub-comoponent